# Postgres complaining to cast enum to a string only if used in else

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 11.

When I run this query:

```
UPDATE "Push"
SET "state" = CASE id WHEN 46 THEN 'ABANDONED' else 'COMPLETED' END
WHERE id in (46,47)
```

Postgres complains with:

> column "state" is of type "PushState" but expression is of type text
> HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

However if I remove the `'COMPLETED'` from the `else` and put in `else "state"` it works without the error.

```
UPDATE "Push"
SET "state" = CASE id WHEN 46 THEN 'ABANDONED' WHEN 47 THEN 'COMPLETED' else "state" END
WHERE id in (46,47)
```

I don't understand why it's doing this. Does anyone know? Ideally I would like to go with my first version.

Comment: All the clause of `CASE` have to return the same type and you are not. The first two return strings and the `else`  is returning  an `enum` value.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table s (id int,state PushState);
insert into s (values(46,'ABANDONED'::PushState),(47,'MISC'));

UPDATE  s
SET state = CASE id WHEN 46 THEN 'ABANDONED'::pushstate else 'COMPLETED' END
WHERE id in (46,47);
```

because enum can only represent less text value range, you cannot implicitly cast from text to enum. it's doable other way around.
postgres cannot know this text will aslo match the enum criteria. So you need explicit cast.

Comment: Seems like just an over site during re-writing, but need to case each value so: `... else 'COMPLETED'::pushstate end`.